# Не работает выборка из option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

почему на работает выборка элементов?

```js
$('.opt_urk').click(function() {
    $('.price_second').css('display','none');
});

$('.opt_russ').click(function() {
    $('.price').css('display','none');
});
```

```html
<!-- price 1 -->
  <div class="price">
   <div class="price1">
    <span>Обычная цена:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_1">1798 <span>грн.</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="price2">
    <span>Цена со скидкой:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_2">899 <span>грн.</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- price 2 -->
  <div class="price_second">
   <div class="price1">
    <span>Обычная цена:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_1">1599  <span>руб.</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="price2">
    <span>Цена со скидкой:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_2">3198  <span>руб.</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input_box">
   <form>
    <select name="Страна">
     <option value="Страна">Страна </option>
     <option value="Украина " class="opt_urk">Украина </option>
     <option value="Россия" class="opt_russ">Россия</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Номер телефона">
    <button><a href="">Заказать сейчас</a></button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <!-- price 2 -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: потому что событие надо вешать к селекту на его изменение, а не на пункт.

Comment: тоесть????.....

Comment: а, пардоньте.. чего у вас вообще не работает то? блоки скрываются, что еще то надо?

Comment: ошибок в консоле нету. нужно чтобы при клике на нужный селект блок первый с ценной скрывался

Comment: дак и скрывается вроде, или не то скрывается?

Comment: вообще не работает((